# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick error on button inside datatable

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am having some problems using datatables.net with requirejs and some buttons and data loaded through the ajax request from datatables.net (JSON). I have tried and tried but still no luck.

The problem I face is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: editPermission is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (permissions.php:1)`

Here is the full backend PHP function that is connecting to the DB:

```
public function getAllPermissions($request, $columns): array
    {
        $bindings = array();

        try {
            $sql = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.category, NULL AS roles,
                    CASE WHEN
                      p.required = 0 THEN concat('<button id=\'editpermission_', p.id, '\' onclick=\'editPermission(',p.id,')\' class=\'btn btn-warning\'>Edit</button>')
                      ELSE null END
                    AS edit
                    FROM ".$this->tbl_permissions." p";

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute();
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $return_data = array(
              "data" => MiscFunctions::data_output($columns, $data)
            );

            return $return_data;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            http_response_code(500);
            $result = ["Error" => $e->getMessage()];
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Under here is the file that ajax asks for the data (permissions_getall.php):

```
<?php
try {
    require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $request = new PHPLogin\CSRFHandler;
    $auth = new PHPLogin\AuthorizationHandler;
    $admin = new PHPLogin\AdminFunctions;

    if ($request->valid_token() && ($auth->isSuperAdmin() || $auth->hasPermission('View Permissions'))) {
        unset($_GET['csrf_token']);
        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
            array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 1 ),
            array( 'db' => 'description', 'dt' => 2 ),
            array( 'db' => 'category', 'dt' => 3 ),
            array( 'db' => 'roles', 'dt' => 4 ),
            array( 'db' => 'edit', 'dt' => 5 )
        );

        $data = $admin->getAllPermissions($_GET, $columns);

        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        http_response_code(401);
        throw new Exception('Unauthorized');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
```

This is the JS file:

```
require(['jquery', 'multiselect', 'datatables', 'datatables.net', 'datatables.net-bs4', 'datatables.net-buttons', 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4', 'datatables.net-select-bs4', 'loadingoverlay'], function ($) {
    console.log($);
//User Management scripts
    /* HANDLES POPOVERS FOR USER INFO */
    function userInfoPull(id, elem) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/user_getinfo.php",
            data: {"user_id": id, "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")},
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (user_info) {
                user_info = JSON.parse(user_info);
                var user_info_html = '';
                for (var prop in user_info) {
                    if (user_info[prop] != '' && user_info[prop] != null) {
                        if (prop == 'UserImage') {
                            user_info_html += '<br><div class="img-thumbnail"><img src="' + user_info[prop] + '" height="240px"></div>';
                        } else {
                            user_info_html += '<div><b>' + prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1') + ': </b>' + user_info[prop] + '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $(elem).attr('data-content', user_info_html).popover('show', {"html": true});
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };

    $('body').on('mouseover', "a[id^='info_']", function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-content')) {
            $(this).popover('show', {"html": true});
        } else {
            var id = this.id.split('_')[1];
            userInfoPull(id, this);
        }
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', "a[id^='info_']", function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });
    /****************************/


    /* HANDLES MODAL FOR PERMISSION ROLES */
    $('body').on('click', "button[id^='rolesbtn_']", function () {
        var id = this.id.split('_')[1];
        permissionRolesList(id);
    });

    function permissionRolesList(id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/permission_getroles.php",
            data: {"permission_id": id, "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (role_array) {
                role_array = JSON.parse(role_array);
                $('#permissionsButton').click();
                $('#roles-selected').empty();
                $('#roles-available').empty();
                $('#permission_id').val(id);

                $.each(role_array['permission_roles'], function (key, value) {
                    $('#roles-selected').append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>");
                });
                $.each(role_array['diff_roles'], function (key, value) {
                    $('#roles-available').append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>");
                })

                $("select[id^='roles-']").multiselect({
                    search: {
                        left: '<input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />',
                        right: '<input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />',
                    },
                    fireSearch: function (value) {
                        return value.length > 3;
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };

    function editPermission(id) {

        var id = id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/permission_getdata.php",
            data: {"permission_id": id, "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var respdata = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#editPermissionForm").trigger("reset");
                $("#edit_permission_id").val(respdata.id);
                $("#edit_PermissionName").val(respdata.name);
                $("#edit_PermissionDescription").val(respdata.description);
                $("#edit_PermissionCategory").val(respdata.category);
                $('#editPermission').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#saveRoles').click(function () {

        var sendData = new FormData();
        var formData = [];
        var new_roles = [];

        var id = $('#permission_id').val();

        $('#roles-selected > option').each(function () {
            new_roles.push($(this).val());
        });

        formJson = JSON.stringify(new_roles);
        sendData.append('formData', formJson);
        sendData.append('permissionId', id);
        sendData.append('csrf_token', $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value"));

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/permission_updateroles.php",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: sendData,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                permissionTable.ajax.reload();
                $('#permissionsModal').modal('toggle');
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
    /****************************/


    /* DATATABLE INITIALIZATION */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        permissionTable = $('#permissionList').DataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            order: [[3, "asc"], [1, "asc"]],
            columns: [
                {
                    name: "id",
                    visible: true,
                    searchable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "";
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: "name",
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: "description",
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: "category",
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: "assign roles",
                    width: "90px",
                    searchable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<button id='rolesbtn_" + row[0] + "' class='btn btn-info'>Assign roles</button>"
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: "edit permission",
                    width: "40px",
                    searchable: false
                }
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0
            }],
            paging: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "ajax/permissions_getall.php?csrf_token=" + $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value"),
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    alert(xhr.responseJSON.Error);
                }
            },
            scrollY: "600px",
            scrollCollapse: true,
            lengthMenu: [[15, 30, -1], [15, 30, "All"]],
            select: {
                style: "multi",
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'selectAll',
                    className: 'selectall',
                    action: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        permissionTable.rows({page: 'current'}).select();
                        permissionTable.rows({search: 'removed'}).deselect();
                    }
                },
                "selectNone",
                {
                    text: 'Add New Permission',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        $('#newPermission').modal('show');
                    },
                    className: "btn-success"
                },
                {
                    text: 'Delete Selected',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        var selected_array = dt.rows({selected: true}).data();
                        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected permissions?")) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = selected_array.length; i < len; i++) {

                                deletePermission(selected_array[i][0], 'rolesbtn_' + selected_array[i][0]);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    className: "btn-danger"
                }
            ]
        }).on("select", function () {
            //console.log("selected");
        });

    });

    /****************************/


    function deletePermission(id, btn_id) {
        var idJSON = "[" + JSON.stringify(id) + "]";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/permissions_delete.php",
            data: {"ids": idJSON, "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")},
            async: false,
            success: function (resp) {
                permissionTable.row($('#' + btn_id).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }


    $("#newPermissionForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var permissionName = $("#new_PermissionName").val();
        var permissionDescription = $("#new_PermissionDescription").val();
        var permissionCategory = $("#new_PermissionCategory").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/permissions_add.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "permissionName": permissionName,
                "permissionDescription": permissionDescription,
                "permissionCategory": permissionCategory,
                "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function (resp) {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                permissionTable.ajax.reload();
                $("#newPermission").modal('hide');
                $("#newPermissionForm")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#editPermissionForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var permissionId = $("#edit_permission_id").val();
        var permissionName = $("#edit_PermissionName").val();
        var permissionDescription = $("#edit_PermissionDescription").val();
        var permissionCategory = $("#edit_PermissionCategory").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/permission_update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "permissionId": permissionId,
                "permissionName": permissionName,
                "permissionDescription": permissionDescription,
                "permissionCategory": permissionCategory,
                "csrf_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr("value")
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    image: '../login/images/Spin-0.8s-200px.svg',
                    imageAnimation: false,
                    imageColor: '#428bca',
                    fade: [200, 100]
                });
            },
            complete: function (resp) {
                $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                permissionTable.ajax.reload();
                $("#editPermission").modal('hide');
                $("#editPermissionForm")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });

//Role assignment box button logic
    (function () {
        $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#roles-available option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('#roles-selected').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#btnAllRight').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#roles-available option');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('#roles-selected').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#roles-selected option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('#roles-available').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#btnAllLeft').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#roles-selected option');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $('#roles-available').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }(jQuery));

// Converts array to object
    function toObject(arr) {
        var rv = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
            rv[i] = arr[i];
        return rv;
    }
});
```

Here is a image of the page with the button that is causing problems circled:

[image: Page with buttons in question]

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Attempted to move the function editPermission around as well as placing it inside the `$(document).ready`
2. I have noticed that when I click it in Chrome it seems to open a new page where it executes the script. Sort of weird. Screenshot (Normal page file circled):

   [image: Weird behaviour]

What things can I try to solve this?

Comment: All the functions defined in the JS file are local to the callback function of `require`. They need to be global if you want to call them from `onclick`

Comment: So how to do it in the best way in this case you think. Move it outside the require part? Edit: You are epic! Worked by just moving the editPermission function to the top of document before i use requirejs. Thank you so much! If you post that as solution i will accept